# How to write the logical operations of grammar rule in the most optimized way in antlr4?

Tags: antlr, antlr4

How to write the logical operations of grammar rule in the most optimized way in antlr4?

For example,

Approach #1

```
logicalExpression: expression ('EQUALS' | 'NOT EQUALS' | 'GREATER_THAN' | 'LESS_THAN') value;
```

vs

Approach #2

```
logicalExpression
    : expression 'EQUALS' value
    | expression 'NOT EQUALS' value
    | expression 'GREATER_THAN' value
    | expression 'LESS_THAN' value
```

Which is approach is more efficient/performant? and Why?
I have a feeling expression will be matched multiple times in approach#2 rather than just once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first approach is more efficient. Just look at the underlying ATN:

[image]

versus

[image]

When the parser walks the ATN to predict the match it has to check one path after the other. In the second approach it has to evaluate the left hand `expression` node for every possible operator. The first variant is much more efficient, since it evaluates that only once and quickly decides based on a single operator check, instead.